# Showing that $f(0)e^{cx} \le f(x) \le f(0)^{Cx}$ applies for $f$ differentiable in $[0;b)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Be $f$ differentiable in $I = [0;b)$, then if $:\exists c,C:\forall x \in I \in {\mathbb{R}}$ so that:

$$cf(x) \le f'(x) \le Cf(x)$$

then:

$$f(0)e^{cx} \le f(x) \le f(0)^{Cx}$$

I am really confused how to show that the second part follows from the first and I am at a loss on how to start. Any hint on why this applies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$cf(x) \le f'(x) \le Cf(x)$$

Break this into $2$ inequalities:

$cf(x) \le f'(x)$ and $ f'(x) \le Cf(x)$

Now, from $cf(x) \le f'(x)$, we get $$c \le \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
$$\Rightarrow \int c dx \le \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx$$
$$\Rightarrow cx+c_1 \le \ln f(x) \,\,\,\, \text{where } c_1 \text{ is an integration constant}$$
$$\Rightarrow cx+ \ln f(0) \le \ln f(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow f(0)e^{cx} \le f(x)$$

Similarly, from the other inequality, you can show that 
$$\Rightarrow f(x) \le f(0)e^{Cx}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, we didn't have integrals just yet, I I don't understand how $\Rightarrow \int c dx \le \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx = ln f(x)$. I am also unsure we would be able to use it.

Comment: Is there maybe an alternate way without using integration?

Comment: Well that's integration. It follows from the rules. In case, you don't know integration, you can also go for Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: Then, of course, you will have to go backwards. That is, assume the result is true and prove the given statement.

Comment: I think that will work, thanks.